# Как анимировать css или svg градиент в SVG?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, svg-animation

Нужно сделать эффект заполнения цветом одной буквы, как на гифке.
Кроме, как заполнить градиентом, я не придумал, как это сделать, но проблема в том, что transition не работает на `linear-gradient`, keyframes тоже не делает анимацию с градиентом, я решил использовать SVG анимацию, но если туда просто прописать значения градиента то он не работает, как это реализовать?

https://jsfiddle.net/morskaya_ulitochka/1k7bjwzs/17/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что означает - **вытекающего текста**? Текст должен анимироваться относительно прямоугольника? или анимация заполнения цветом самих букв?

Comment: Сделайте два градиента в одном, анимируйте позицию фона (background-position).

Comment: @Alexandr_TT анимация заполнения цветом самих букв

Comment: @Artyom Заполнение букв сверху-вниз?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT сперва буква белая, в конце чёрная с белой обводкой

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эффект достигается анимацией атрибута `offset` линейного градиента:

```
 <stop offset="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
```

**Заполнение цветом сверху-вниз**

*Анимация начнется после клика*

```css
#txt {
stroke:white;
stroke-width:4px;
font-size:100px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;
text-anchor:middle;
alignment-baseline:central;
fill:url(#top_bottom);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="background-color:#111111" >  
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="top_bottom" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>        

<text id="txt" x="50%" y="50%">TEXT </text>
</svg>
```

**Заполнение цветом слева-направо**

```css
#txt {
stroke:white;
stroke-width:4px;
font-size:100px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;
text-anchor:middle;
alignment-baseline:central;
fill:url(#left_right);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="background-color:#111111" >  
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="left_right" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" />
      </stop>
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>        

<text id="txt" x="50%" y="50%">TEXT </text>
</svg>
```

### Анимация заполнением градиентом только одной буквы

Используется теги `<tspan>X</tspan>`, чтобы разбить слово на буквы и применить анимацию только к одной букве

```css
#txt {
stroke:white;
fill:white;
stroke-width:4px;
font-size:90px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;
/*fill:url(#top_bottom);*/
}
tspan#x {
fill:url(#top_bottom);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="background-color:#111111" >  
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="top_bottom" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"  />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"  />
      </stop>
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>        

<text id="txt" x="10" y="180">
  <tspan >TE</tspan>
   <tspan id="x" dx="-20">X </taspan>
   <tspan dx="-20" fill="white">T</tspan> 

</text>
</svg>
```

Бесконечное повторение `repeatCount="indefinite"`

```css
#txt {
stroke:white;
fill:white;
stroke-width:4px;
font-size:90px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;

}
tspan#x {
fill:url(#top_bottom);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="background-color:#111111" >  
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="top_bottom" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>        

<text id="txt" x="10" y="180">
  <tspan >TE</tspan>
   <tspan id="x" dx="-20">X </taspan>
   <tspan dx="-20" fill="white">T</tspan> 

</text>
</svg>
```

Вариант интересного эффекта

```css
#txt {
stroke:white;
fill:white;
stroke-width:4px;
font-size:90px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:verdana;

}
tspan#x {
fill:url(#top_bottom);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300" style="background-color:#111111" >  
 <defs>
    <linearGradient id="top_bottom" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="black">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </stop>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="white">
        <animate begin="svg1.click" dur="2s" attributeName="offset" fill="freeze" from="0" to="1"  />
      </stop>
      
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>        

<text id="txt" x="10" y="180">
  <tspan >TE</tspan>
   <tspan id="x" dx="-20">X </taspan>
   <tspan dx="-20" fill="white">T</tspan> 

</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Саша там скриншот... я ему сделал на тостере одну букву ...но он молчит

Comment: классно..но больше одного плюса я не смогу поставить

Comment: Саша закрой вопрос и  всё

Comment: Кстати доклад Джейка Арчибальда видел ?

Comment: @MaximLensky нет, кинь ссылку, было бы интересно почитать. Ведь он первый придумал фокусы с рисованием линий и оптимизатор кода очень хороший у него

Comment: там видео: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0&t=1303s  если eng знаешь - то сможешь узнать полезное

Comment: да но 0 поставишь